# Is it possible to edit/add PDF tags without adobe reader?

Tags: php, pdf, accessibility

Adobe Acrobat Pro allows you to modify your PDF documents tags (add HTML h1, h2, p, list tags, etc) through the software. There are also PDF accessibility add-ons for Adobe Acrobat such as CommonLook, but from what I can see these are just add-ons and there is nothing out there that operates completely independently from the Acrobat application.

Basically, I'm wondering if it would be possible to create a custom web application in PHP to modify these accessibility tags completely separate from any adobe application. With enough knowledge of the PDF document structure would this be doable?

You can see what I'm referring to by PDF tags here:
https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/pdf-tagging.pdf

Comment: Definitely not easy. But theoretically possible, yes. PDF is a fully open format, you can still find a more or less up to date PDF Specification document on the Adobe web site as part of the Acrobat SDK (even though the latest version is now an ISO standard document that you can't get for free any more).

Comment: There's at least one software library which does this (implemented in Java, IIRC)